# Pea protein in a yeast dough. No rise in oven?

Tags: baking, dough, pizza

Spent whole week making no rise no kneed pizza dough (1.5Tbsp yeast + 1.5 cup water + 4 cups flour etc). Gets pretty puffy in the oven.

Today tried adding pea protein (70g, but with less flour to achieve same level of sticky consistency) and it completed killed it rising in the oven.

**Too much pea protein or some properties of pea protein specifically?** Besides being pretty fibery it seems pea protein also binds water easily.

Comment: How much of the flour was replaced with pea protien?  You use volume for one and weight for the other, so I can't really tell.

Answer (score 3):

The use of legume flours like pea flour is known to compromise gluten formation in the dough, leading to poor gas retention. See, for instance, [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4152488/) on the use of gram flour in wheat bread. It's not clear from your question what percentage of pea flour you're using, but based on that data I wouldn't advise more than ten percent. You could try adding additional wheat gluten to the dough to compensate. You should also be measuring by relative mass, not by how 'sticky' the dough feels.